# How to get pending local notifications

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa

How does an application get information about local ios notifications.  Specifically, how can I cancel all pending local notifications belonging to a particular app like Facebook, etc.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To get remaining all local notification

```
NSLog(@"%@",[[UIApplication sharedApplication]scheduledLocalNotifications]);
```

and to cancel all local notification

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication]cancelAllLocalNotifications];
```

Maybe it will help you.